# os.path.getsize() not working on network drive

Tags: python, path, size, os.path

I'm trying to collect information on specific folders on my network when running this script. Currently, I'm running this code from a MacBookPro but in the end, I will mostly use it on Win10. The code works like charm on local folders and files. But as soon as I try to run it on my Network SMB Drive. Everything runs nicely but shows 0 as size which is not the actual size.
As said on local folders it collects the right information.
I hope somebody has an advice about this as I get no error message or anything else.

```
def get_size(scan_paths = '.'):
    """Gets the size of the given folder path and returns the size in GB"""
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(scan_paths):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            # skip if it is symbolic link
            if not os.path.islink(fp):
                total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return ", ".join(map(str, (round(total_size/1000/1000/1000, 2), 'GB'))).replace(', ', '')
```

Comment: As an aside, is there any particular reason you're using os instead of pathlib?

Comment: I tired pathlip for the first time today and couldn't figure out how it works for now. And I have scripts running with os so that's why I did it this way for now :) Most of the software is bounding me to Python 2.7 but I'm trying to use 3.7 for Software that supports it.